# Initializing a variable if it wasn't already passed to the function. Is this the right way?

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

I've seen this convention in several scripts I've encountered. It's supposed to initialize an empty options object if none are passed to the function:

```
module.exports = function (opts) {
  // Create empty options if none are passed
  opts = opts || {};
};
```

But in reading this I was wondering, will this not create a global `opts` variable? Wouldn't it be better to prefix it with `var`? Or will the commonjs module style prevent this?

Comment: Globals are awful practice. This function only cares about `opts` being passed in. The function needs `opts` to be an object, so it's either using the object passed in or creating its own.

Comment: It's not global because you are accessing the local variable `opts` passed in as a parameter.

Comment: No, the scope of this variable is within the function in which it is an argument of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The variable `opts` is declared in the function signature as parameter. It is thereby scoped to the function. Declaring a variable as parameter has essentially the same effect as `var ..` (plus, it's a parameter). You're just reassigning a new value to that variable.

Comment: So if the variable is created with the function, what value will `opts` have if no parameters are passed to the function? Will the value be `undefined`, and that's why it will create a new `opts` object when no parameters are passed?

Comment: If you don't pass an argument the variable `opts` will still exist perfectly fine and hold the value `undefined`. So then its value will be overwritten with an empty object.

Answer (score 1):

It [does not create a global variable](http://jsfiddle.net/sxjg7w4f/) since it is already in the scope of your function as it is the function's argument.

```
var test = function (opts) {
  // Create empty options if none are passed
  opts = opts || {};
};

test({ "test" : true });

alert(typeof opts); // opts is undefined
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for writing out the test!